# pdf hosting and disk space

Tags: disk, diskspace

While I can't leak too much information about this, there is a website I am thinking about making that would be large and would have A LOT of pdf files.  However, disk space doesn't come cheap.  How would I make it so that I can host all these pdfs (users would post them too) without eating up all this disk space?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do some checks on the markup of the PDF? Or set a max file-size, maybe a set of maxium file-sizes depending on the amount of pages?

I'm using pdf2html to handle (=get text from) PDF files.

It's a bit difficult to say... do the PDF's contain images or other data that will 'shrink' kb's?

Comment: The pdfs would be able to have images in them and could potentially be quite long.

Answer (score 0):

That is kind of like asking how you you store trillions of gallons of salt water but not create an ocean. It really cant be done. At the best, you would manage your resources to cut down on the space a bit. For instance, if your PDFs can be turned into Forms, them just have the data and links to the embedded images in an xfdf file, that might cut down a percentage. But there are of course caveats. 1) this wont work if your PDFs arent forms and cant be standardized. 2) If your PDFs are mostly just images in a PDF format, this wont really help at all.

Comment: Oh yeah, and everybody in on this cloud-love thing right now. Needless to say, the cloud you are paying per kb of traffic moved around and stored which might be very expensive for you, more so than maintaining the hard drives.